# Android jsonobject to listview socketio

Tags: android, json, node.js, socket.io, gson

I made a chat app using `socket.io` and `node.js` and I got data like as in JSON object.
**Here is my code**

```
db.query('select email from users ', function(err, rows , field) {
    if (err) throw err;  
    let getuser={"get":rows};
    socket.emit('getuser',getuser);
});
```

In android I get the data and show the email data using `Toast.makeText`

```
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
     try {
       String get =data.getString("get");
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), get, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } catch (JSONException e) {}
```

But I wanna show email list (userlist) by using  a simple `ListView`.
How can I get a string array from a JSON object?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get JSON Array from JSONObject then convert it to List of model class by loop and parse it or by GSON Library then show result list on ListView

```
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
try {
    JSONArray userlist = data.getJSONArray("get");
} catch (JSONException e) {}
```